# Get exact color match using Imagick::compositeImage

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I want to combine two images, one of which is a pattern image and another is color mask.

My problem is the color I get does not match the one I want to receive.

This is my "pattern image" $image:

[image]

I then use

`$image->compositeImage($ribbon, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COLORBURN, 0, 0);`

to combine it with 'color' image

[image]

I am expecting the output similar to this:

[image]

but what I get is:

[image]

The lighter and darker areas come from pattern image, but in general this different color than I would expect. I also tried every other option, including `Imagick::COMPOSITE_HARDLIGHT`, `Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVERLAY` etc.

What do I miss here? Maybe I need to make some preparation for $image first? Or use different method of merging images together?

UPD: 
If I use COMPOSITE_COLORIZE I also don't get the color I need, but much lighter instead
[image]

Comment: Did you try COMPOSITE_COLORIZE

Comment: Yes I did try that. Updated my post with the image I get in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I do not code Imagick well. But you can try the following in Imagemagick (unix syntax). First, I make the image so that white becomes transparent. Then I trim the white off of the pattern image and tile it out. Then I extract the alpha channel of the image. Then I do a compose multiply using all 3 images where the alpha channel is used as a mask.

```
convert \( image.png -alpha off -colorspace gray \
-fuzz 2% -transparent white \) \
\( pattern.png -fuzz 20% -trim +repage -write mpr:pattern \
+delete -size 200x152 tile:mpr:pattern \) \
\( -clone 0 -alpha extract \) \
-alpha off -compose multiply -composite result.png
```

[image]

Alternately, doing each step separately and saving the results, which may be easier to convert to Imagick, you can do:

```
convert image.png -alpha off -colorspace gray grayimage.png
convert pattern.png -fuzz 20% -trim +repage trimpattern.png 
convert -size 200x152 tile:trimpattern.png tiledpattern.png
convert grayimage.png tiledpattern.png -compose multiply -composite multipliedimage.png
convert grayimage.png -fuzz 2% -transparent white -alpha extract alphaimage.png
convert multipliedimage.png alphaimage.png -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite -compose over -background white -flatten result2.png
```

[image]